# Zooming in / out in Neatbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Is there a way to zoom in / out while in debug mode?
I know about **alt+scroll** option but this does not work when debugging for the lower console where you actually get to see what is happening (i think its called variables tab).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it is not possible. Unlike windows containing pure text, dynamically zooming in/out in debugging windows such as **Variables** and **Watches** is not supported in NetBeans. The same is true in Eclipse.

Presumably this is because those windows are interactive, and contain more than just text (tree structures, icons, input fields, etc.).

That said, you can specify the font size for the entire IDE itself when starting NetBeans, and that would increase/decrease the font size in the **Variables** window accordingly. For example, to set the IDE's font size to 16, just add the parameter **--fontsize 16** to your call to run NetBeans. (I realize that you specifically want to be able to zoom in/out freely, but thought it worth mentioning just in case you were desperate to modify the font size in the **Variables** window. See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize for details.)

Comment: yeah, i figured out the font size - guess I was hoping there is another way...cheers tho!